# Calculate $ \iiint_{D} e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p} d x d y d z $

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Calculate 
$$
I = \iiint_{D} e^{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^p} d x d y d z, D = \{x,y,z: x>0, y>0, z>0 \}.
$$
I used spherical coordinates and get an answer $\frac{\pi}{4p} \Gamma(\frac32 p) $. My solution:
$$
I = \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\int\limits_0^{+\infty} d r d \varphi d \theta e^{-r^{2p}} r^2 \sin \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} \int\limits_0^{\infty} e^{-r^{2p}} r^2 d r
$$
Then I make change of variables
$$
t = r^{2p}, r = t^{1/2p}, d r = \frac{t^{\frac{1-2p}{2p}}}{2p} d t
$$
So we have
$$
I = \frac {\pi}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t} t^{1/p} t^{\frac{1-2p}{2p}}}{2p} dt = \frac{\pi}{4p} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{\frac32 p - 1} d t = \frac{\pi}{4p} \Gamma(\frac32 p).
$$
Is that correct? Seems a little bit dubious.

Comment: Just a suggestion for next time: It would be better if you could show your **full** working out, since this allows us to pick up the portions where you've gone wrong. That way, if you got a wrong solution, we do not provide hints you already know and you can easily correct your mistakes.

Comment: Good job on adding your working out! (+1)

Comment: "Seems a little bit dubious." Why?

Comment: @Kamil It's almost right, the only problem is that in the last integral, the exponent of $t$ should be $\frac{3}{2p} - 1$ instead of $\frac{3}{2}p - 1$.

Comment: The last integral is calculated by definition of Gamma-function. May you specify your question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Result using Wolfram for $Re(p)>0$:
$$\int^{+\infty}_{0}\int^{+\infty}_{0}\int^{+\infty}_{0}e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{p}}dxdydz=\dfrac{1}{6}\pi \Gamma \left( 1+\dfrac{3}{2p}\right)$$

The $p$ is in the denominator.
$$\dfrac{\pi}{4p}\int^{+\infty}_{0}e^{-t}t^{-1+\frac{3}{2p}}dt=\dfrac{\pi}{4p}\Gamma\left( \dfrac{3}{2p}\right)=$$Using $\Gamma(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\Gamma (x+1)$
$$=\dfrac{\pi}{4p}\cdot \dfrac{2p}{3}\Gamma\left( 1+\dfrac{3}{2p}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{6}\Gamma \left( 1+\dfrac{3}{2p}\right)$$